# How do I remove the parent element?

Tags: jquery

I'm brand new to jquery and am not even sure if I'm referring correctly to the "parent" element. I want to remove the two `<li>` tags completely. Is there a way to do this with only a single id declaration?

```
<li class="remove"><a href="#">ds</a></li>
<li class="remove"><a href="#">xfg</a></li>

<li><a href="#">ds</a></li>   <------This stays as well as the one below
<li><a href="#">xfg</a></li>
```

Comment: The example you've posted makes it look like you just want to remove the `class` attribute from both `li` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
$('.remove').remove(); // all which matches a class="remove" will be gone completely.
```

or by click of it's `<a>`

```
$('#ulID li a').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.remove').remove();
   return false; // prevent link to jump to a page.
});
```

<sub>Welcome to [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com)</sub>
<sub>Don't forget to accept an answer</sub>

Comment: Reigel, that worked, thank you. Also, thank you for the comments in the code, it helps me understand.

Comment: Thank you, Reigel. I'm sure I'll be back often. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.remove').remove()
```