# How to Disable a specific link using html or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess

I am using a Gchat voice and video chat script. link to my [website](http://www.pklovers.net)

The problem is that someone login in my chatroom and he use this flash [link](http://best-hosting.cu.cc/c/banner3-www-facebook-skype-net-com.swf)  to crash users browser.

when he login all of us get disconnected and we have a blank black page at that time.

He must be using `src="http://best-hosting.cu.cc/c/banner3-www-facebook-skype-net-com.swf"` or iframe of that link somewhere when he is logging in.

Please help me. How can I disable that flash thing not to load in all users browsers

I get his links detect using ads block plus extension in firefox when he login with that flash link thing. when i block his link in ads block plus then i do not get disconnect but the other users who dont have ads block plus still get disconnect from website and have a blank black page.

Please suggest me something that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the accepted answer here: [Find text and remove it jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087972/find-text-and-remove-it-jquery)

Use it to find a string within the text and remove the entire thing.

I'd personally do: `$('.className').contains('.swf').remove();​`

Where className would be the class for links, or you could just do it for the `<a>` tag in general

**EDIT:** That being said, I have no idea what Gchat is, and whether or not this would be possible with it. If it is something hosted on your site it should work, but if it is embedded and hosted elsewhere, I'm not quite sure, worth a try though.